# Accessing Spring Bean without servlet/webapp context

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I have a spring based webapp and I also have a background process. From inside the background process, I would like to be able to access spring beans. I normally retrieve spring beans by using:

```
ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
Object mySpringBean = context.getBean("mySpringBean");
```

The problem is that my background process is not servlet based and does not have access to the servletContext. The background process is triggered by a proprietary task execution program. This task execution program uses Class.forName to instantiate my background process and I am not permitted to modify the task execution program.

Is it possible for my background process to access spring beans? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?`

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring-activemq/spring-activemq-producer-nio.xml");
```

All you have to do is specify where your XML is

Comment: Would this cause Spring to instantiate an additional instance of every bean in my xml file? Or would it access the Spring context which was created by the webapp? Alternatively, I could create a separate xml file listing only the beans needed by my background process. Would that be better?

Comment: David, the latter would be better.  It means more maintenance on the distinct context files as your beans change over time, but it's worth it.

Comment: It will create a brand new Spring context, without any link with the one create by the webapp.

Comment: I really think that there will be two separate contexts, one by your background process and one in the webapp.

Comment: I agree with the other comments.  This is not a good answer, it will create a new context.

Comment: @aweigold agree, but the question was not about a different or not context. You can answer yourself really. I will vote you up for a solution

Comment: @Eugene, posted (was already working on it before I saw your comment :-) )

Answer (score 4):

First off, my solution here is not ideal.  Before using this, think about the architecture of your application, more than likely, you can make a structural change to get access to the context.

If you have multiple contexts you are maintaining, you will obviously need to add a bit more logic in here to sort them out.

You can create an ApplicationContextAware bean, and access your context via a static:

```
@Component
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<? extends T> beanClass) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    protected static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return SpringApplicationContext.CONTEXT;
    }
}
```

Another option, is if you have a way to register the context in your background process, you can do that in the setApplicationContext method.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext for loading the Spring context :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/path/to/applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: OK, but those won't be the same beans the servlet is using. The background process will have its own spring context and re-create these beans.

Answer (score 0):

Your background process must manually create the context.  Typically this is done once during process initialization.

Something like:

ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( new String[] { "appContext.xml" }, true );